# Linq To Entities bad SQL casting in where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, hyperlink

I've just encountered a strange issue with Linq To Entities.
Here is the background :
- Entity Code First
- This entity is mapped to an SQL Server View

When trying a deffered execution such as

```
byte id = 1;

var query = myDbSet.Where(s => s.SiteId == id);

query = query.Where(s => s.Type == "Some Type");

var lst = query.ToList();
```

I get a timeout from SQL Server (the query lasts for 1 min).

When profiling the SQL query I see a strange casting from SiteId to int, whereas it is tinyint.
By executing the same query removing the cast, the query lasts for 3 seconds !

How can I force the parameter type not to have some SQL casting ?

Comment: Side note - your statement `query.Where(s => s.Type == "Some Type");` doesn't actually do anything, because you haven't assigned it anywhere.  If you want to filter on that you'd have to do `query = query.Where(s => s.Type == "Some Type");`

Comment: well seen ! It's not the real code... I wrote it in the question so there may be some mistakes... Changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Where clause by :

```
var query = MyDbSet.Where( s => id.Equals(s.SiteID));
```

solved the issue !